# Publishing Blazor App using Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, azure-app-service-plans, blazor-server-side

I have a server side blazor app, I would like to publish it using Azure App Service. When I send the publish command from within Visual Studio, I got this message.

[image]

Does this mean I cannot use this method to publish server side blazor app right now? What is the alternative way?

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543379/how-can-i-deploy-a-blazor-server-hosted-application-from-visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 1):

Change the Deployment Mode in your Publish settings to "Self-Contained."