# How to downgrade Blazor app from .Net Core 3 to .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have finished Blazor application using .Net Core 3 on Visual studio 2019 Community (Not Preview), but when I tried to publishing it on the host I found that the host doesn't support .Net Core 3, only supports version 2.1,2.2, and technical support told me to subscribe to another hosting plan and it is very expensive at least for now

I tried to downgrade the .Net core version in the application but so many errors appeared like that image

[image]

I tried to create a new Blazor project with .Net Core 2.2, but Blazor just exists in version 3

I need to find any way to downgrade my app .Net core version to 2.2 and keep at least the basic features of Blazor

Comment: May be you can try to deploy it in sefl contained mode. This way you don't have to install the framework. `dotnet publish --self-contained`

Comment: @aguafrommars yes I did that but didn't work

Comment: I have pushed the previous preview on the F1 (free) service plan on Azure. Did you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56543379/60761 ?

Comment: And you should be using the Preview edition of VS.

Answer (score 4):

There's not much you can do on this one, Blazor runs on .NET Core 3, you can't run it on a lower version of .NET Core.

However, if you're running client-side Blazor then you don't actually need to run .NET on the server at all as it publishes static files. Otherwise there isn't much you can do.

Comment: I could run blazor on .net core 2 before
https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC880645.png

Comment: For a time Blazor ran on .NET Core 2 but that was quite a while ago.

Comment: If I can get any old Blazor template that work on sdk 2.2 this will be a good solution. Is that right ?

Comment: Possibly, but I really wouldn’t recommend it. You will lose a lot of features and that’s even if you get things working. You would probably have to change back to VS 2017 as well. However, if you want to try I believe all previous releases are under the releases tab of the GitHub repo. But once again I really wouldn’t recommend it.