# How to resolve target-issues in Azure Devops Pipeline when creating Self-contained deployments

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Because Azure AppServices doesn't (anymore) support .NET Core 2.1 on x64 with framework-dependent deployments, we are currently publishing self-contained win-x64 versions of our .NET Core 2.1 Web API.

I'm  trying to setup an Azure Pipeline in Yaml for CI/CD purposes and deploy it to Azure App Service deployment slot.

The issue I'm trying to resolve is this error-message: **project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp2.1/win10-x64'**

```
/usr/bin/dotnet publish /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApp.WebApi/MyApp.WebApi.csproj --configuration Release -f netcoreapp2.1 -r win10-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore --output /home/vsts/work/1/a/MyApp.WebApi

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.3+39993bd9d for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApp.WebApi/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp2.1/win10-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win10-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApp.WebApi/MyApp.WebApi.csproj]
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/dotnet' failed with exit code 1
```

This is my yaml file:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: x64

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'Hangfire Pro'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet publish
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'Hangfire Pro'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) -f netcoreapp2.1 -r win10-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'MyAppWebApi'
```

I tried modifying the CSPROJ file by adding these:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    **<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>**

and

<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

Comment: Btw. I tried switching between ubuntu-20.04/windows-2019. No results. It works when deploying on my machine with Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: And yes, we are planning to go to LTS 3.1 coming months because 2.1 is EOL this summer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things went wrong during my work. The most important one is that all the changes I've tried to make were pushed to the Develop-branch while the Pipeline was running on a different branch. My inexperience with Pipelines (and also Git) mainly caused this. I was under the impression that the `trigger` line in YAML pointed to the repository to restore and publish.

I finally got it working with the following steps. Like Edward Han mentioned, I tried to restore and publish by command line on my local machine. These also gave me some errors I needed to fix. Like adding this line to all (30+) referenced csproj files:

```
<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
```

Then add this configuration to the webproject csproj:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Then my final YAML file is this:

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPlatform: x64

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 2.1.x'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-r win-x64'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'Hangfire Pro'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
   command: 'test'
   projects: '**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'
   arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
   testRunTitle: 'dotnet test 2'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet publish
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) -r win-x64 --self-contained true --no-restore --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

# this code takes all the files in $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and uploads them as an artifact of your build.
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'MyAppWebApi'
```

Few important things I changed/added:

- Explicitly tell to use .NET Core 2.1.*
- Add -runtime parameter to the RESTORE command

**Conslusion**

Although I studied some Pluralsight courses, YouTube video's and blogs, I still ended up reading the Microsoft Docs/MSDN. Being used to use publishing by the Visual Studio User Interface, switching to command-line really was a big difference. A lot more depencenies are needed to be looked at. Tip: really read the urls these error messages provide, they do contain enough information to resolve your issue. At least, that's what I learned.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the obj and bin folders from your project. Also the `<TargetFramework>` in your .csproj file was singular. Please try to add an "s" and it become `"TargetFrameworks"` to see if it works.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842443/asp-net-core-application-net-framework-for-windows-x64-only-error-in-project) for more possible solutions.

BTW, there are different build environment between [Microsoft-hosted Windows-2019 agents](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#microsoft-windows-server-2019-datacenter)(which install Visual Studio Enterprise 2019) and your local machine, you could try to use [self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to build your project without additional environment preparation steps.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the steps you have shown above. Sadly it doesnt make any change. The obj and bin folders are not present in the git repo, so they don't exist yet for this pipeline.

Comment: Does this issue exist when you use [self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops), which will build project with your local Visual Studio2019?